# Backup SharedPreferences in Android to local Server or Device

Tags: android, backup, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

I am developing an App for a lot of Devices, so that they aren't registered to a Google Account.

But I want to backup my `SharedPreferences` somewhere. In best case in a folder on the device.

So I tried to use the `BackupAgentHelper`, but this backups only to Google or can it backup somewhere else ?

Alternatively is there a way to copy the `SharedPreferences` to a place on the sdcard?

The problem is when I doing a update to my app (not trough the market) I lose all my data.

PS: Sorry for my bad englisch

Answer (score 0):

Using `BackupAgentHelper` only uses the in-built Google backup system, and won't do anything useful for you if you don't have a Google Account on the device.

`SharedPreferences` files are just regular files in your app's data directory. If you want to copy them to the SD card, or your own server, on command, you can do that using the normal `File` API. It sounds like for what you're trying to achieve, it might be easiest to just call [`Context.fileList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList%28%29) to get an array of files in your apps' internal storage, and then iterate over that array, copying each file to a folder on the SD card.